# PHP ODBC connection to H2 database

Tags: php, connection-string, h2, unixodbc

could you please assist me with this.

I'm trying to connect to a H2 Database using PHP OBDC and I get the following error message: 
"SQL error: [unixODBC]Unknown authentication type, SQL state 28000 in SQLConnect"

I use the following to connect: 
$DSN = "Driver=PostgreSQL;Server=$Srv;Port=5435;Database=$DB;";
$CID = odbc_connect($DSN,$usr,$pwd);

How do i parse the Authentication type in the connection string.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try including the user and password in the connection string

```
$DSN = "Driver=PostgreSQL;Server=$Srv;Port=5435;Database=$DB;UID=$usr;PWD=$pwd";
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working through the PHP functions for Postgres SQL.

```
$conn = pg_connect("host=[host] port=[port number] dbname=[database name] user=[username] password=[password]");
```

Comment: what port and database name did you put to make the above work? I tried issuing java -cp h2-1.3.172.jar org.h2.tools.Server to run the default h2 server, and it warns "PG server running at pg://127.0.1.1:5435 (only local connections)", however those don't work for me.